# SSRS Report: Use optionset labels of specific language

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm-2011, fetch, bids

we have a Multilanguage MSCRM 2011 environment, with German base language. I want to create a report for all languages, but the labels of optionsets should always be shown in English language independent of the client language.
I am using a Fetch based report.

Is there any possibility to achieve this easily?

Answer (score 2):

If you do SQL-based report you'll find all OptionSet values in the "FilteredStringMap" view.

You'll see there next columns:

- `FilteredViewName` represents the Entity
- `AttributeName` represents the Optionset/TwoOptions fields
- `AttributeValue` represents their values
- `Value` represents the Text of those fields
- `DisplayOrder` represents their display order
- `LangId` represents Language Id (see full list [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms912047%28WinEmbedded.10%29.aspx))

If you do Fetch-based report you can only specify language for the whole report I guess.

Comment: I am using a Fetch based report. But you can only specify the language of a report when uploading to MSCRM and this report is only visible for those who have the language as client language. I want to select 'all languages' when uploading and force the report to use English optionset labels.

Answer (score 0):

We solved the problem by using custom function. In this function we translated the value of the option to english.

```
Function GetEnglishLabel(iOptionValue) As String
    If iOptionValue = 0 Then
        return ""
    End If

    Select Case iOptionValue
        Case 100000000
            return "English label 1"
        Case 100000001
            return "English label 2"
        Case 100000002
            return "English label 3"
        Case 100000003
            return "English label 4"
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Well, that's nice untill you have like 20 values and it's another person who edits them. :-)

Comment: I'm aware of this. But at this moment it seems to be the smartest solution.